# Unable to start a ubuntu container in openshift-origin

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openshift-origin

Am trying to bring up a ubuntu container in a POD in openshift. I have setup my local docker registry and have configured DNS accordingly. Starting the ubuntu container with just docker works fine without any issues. When I deploy the POD, I can see that my docker ubuntu image is pulled successfully, but doesnt succeed in starting the same. It fails with back-off pulling image error. Is this because my entry point does not have any background process running in side the container ?

"openshift.io/container.ubuntu.image.entrypoint": "[\"top\"]",

[Snapshot of the events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdwLs.png)

Deployment-config :

```
{
"kind": "DeploymentConfig",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
    "name": "ubuntu",
    "namespace": "testproject",
    "selfLink": "/oapi/v1/namespaces/testproject/deploymentconfigs/ubuntu",
    "uid": "e7c7b9c6-4dbd-11e6-bd2b-0800277bbed5",
    "resourceVersion": "4340",
    "generation": 6,
    "creationTimestamp": "2016-07-19T14:34:31Z",
    "labels": {
        "app": "ubuntu"
    },
    "annotations": {
        "openshift.io/deployment.cancelled": "4",
        "openshift.io/generated-by": "OpenShiftNewApp"
    }
},
"spec": {
    "strategy": {
        "type": "Rolling",
        "rollingParams": {
            "updatePeriodSeconds": 1,
            "intervalSeconds": 1,
            "timeoutSeconds": 600,
            "maxUnavailable": "25%",
            "maxSurge": "25%"
        },
        "resources": {}
    },
    "triggers": [
        {
            "type": "ConfigChange"
        },
        {
            "type": "ImageChange",
            "imageChangeParams": {
                "automatic": true,
                "containerNames": [
                    "ubuntu"
                ],
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                    "namespace": "testproject",
                    "name": "ubuntu:latest"
                },
                "lastTriggeredImage": "ns1.myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu@sha256:6d9a2a1bacdcb2bd65e36b8f1f557e89abf0f5f987ba68104bcfc76103a08b86"
            }
        }
    ],
    "replicas": 1,
    "test": false,
    "selector": {
        "app": "ubuntu",
        "deploymentconfig": "ubuntu"
    },
    "template": {
        "metadata": {
            "creationTimestamp": null,
            "labels": {
                "app": "ubuntu",
                "deploymentconfig": "ubuntu"
            },
            "annotations": {
                "openshift.io/container.ubuntu.image.entrypoint": "[\"top\"]",
                "openshift.io/generated-by": "OpenShiftNewApp"
            }
        },
        "spec": {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "name": "ubuntu",
                    "image": "ns1.myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu@sha256:6d9a2a1bacdcb2bd65e36b8f1f557e89abf0f5f987ba68104bcfc76103a08b86",
                    "resources": {},
                    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                    "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
                }
            ],
            "restartPolicy": "Always",
            "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
            "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
            "securityContext": {}
        }
    }
},
"status": {
    "latestVersion": 5,
    "details": {
        "causes": [
            {
                "type": "ConfigChange"
            }
        ]
    },
    "observedGeneration": 5
}
```

Comment: Endpoint does not support v2 API. So the pull of the image seems unsuccessfull. Are your pulling from a v1 registry?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the http proxy. After solving that image pull was successful

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue was, so future readers can benefit from this issue?